# Detect if external javascript files are doing something useful inside a page

Tags: javascript, performance

This afternoon I was approached by a client to provide some guidance on how to architect their large code base. The team is knowledgeable about Java, but is unaware of how to build a front-end.

One another concern was performance. The end users were complaining that the page was slow to download. After a couple of questions I was shocked to learn that **80 external Javascript files** might be downloaded (using `<script>` blocks I mean). I'm not kidding.

The Javascript files are supposed to do very standard stuff such as validating, requesting data, etc. I mean there is nothing like enterprisey page doing tons of crazy stuff.

I'd put my head on the block that 95% are outdated code that nobody knows the rationale behind. Just some code that have been out there for a while.

My very first suggestion was to ensure that those files are, say, useful for the purpose.

The manual way would be to inspect the code and comment and uncomment files to check which file is actually used. However it's tedious.

My question is as follow:

Do you a way to automate the check (kind of reporting tool). I mean a tool to check which downloaded files are actually doing something?

Thanks.

R.

Comment: If the files are running, then they're doing *something*. Only a human can decide if that something is *useful* or not. You're basically asking for an AI that understands your intentions :)

Comment: run the profile tool while you use the page. any js calls will be logged with a link to the source file. if you can do everything you need without triggering a script, it can probably be safely removed.